# Error in Oracle event query

Tags: oracle10g

Here I am using query to insert a value into table for every 1 minute cycle through event but its showing Invalid SQL Statement.I am using oracle 10g

```
ON GRANT CREATE EVENT test_event_02
ON SCHEDULE AT SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
insert into tablename values('shree2',SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: what is that error ?

Comment: invalid sql statment

Comment: @user2503585 in  INTERVAL '1' MINUTE remove the quotes like  INTERVAL 1 MINUTE

Comment: @learningNew no still same error

Comment: Why you are using on grant? [see this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-event.html) for correct syntax.

Comment: The Link is showing Example of Mysql Query.